# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound returned when searching for non-existent records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gemset

I' following the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-finding_user_objects). After I created an user, i destroyed it with `destroy` method, then i use `find` to check if it still exist, my console return exactly like the tutorial, but with some errors.
This is error image:
[image]

Here i created a user called "abc" with id: 7, then i destroyed and use `User.find(7)` to find user.

I installed rails with rvm and created gemset named 1.9.3@rails3tutorial2endEd. I searched but don't know what this is problem, can anybody help? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal. Since the record does not exist anymore, you would get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

If you wanted to return `nil` instead. You could try something like

`User.where(:id => 51).exists?`

which will return `true` or false.

Answer (score 1):

Destroyed users cannot be found, since they no longer exist.

Comment: yes, it's returned, but i want to ask what is "from /home/...."? why it appears, what's wrong here?

Comment: Nothing's wrong.  That's part of what is called the stack trace.  The lines at the top of the stack trace ("from /home/... in `find_one`") are the most recent calls.